# Подскажите как расположить элементы рядом, а не один за одним. Чтобы текст был справа, картинки под ним, как на картинке

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][![

```css
*{
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 font-family: "RobotoRegular", sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1;
 background: #f0f0f0;

}
.container{
 width: 800px;
 margin:0 auto;
 min-height: 500px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 background: #fff;
}
.header{

}
.menu{
 width: 230px;
 height: 500px;
    background: #68bdee;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Arial - Bold MT";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
.copy{
 height: 45px;
    background: #da023a;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Arial MT";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 15px 0 13px 15px;
}
.content{
 display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Заголовок страницы</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body> 
 <div class="container">
  <header class="header">
   <h1>
   <img src="star.png">
   <img src="MY_FIRST_CODDING.png">
   <img src="Home_________My_photos_________About_me_________Contact.png">
   </h1>
   <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
   <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li>Menu item 1<a href="#"></a></li>
     <li>Menu item 2<a href="#"></a></li>
     <li>Menu item 3<a href="#"></a></li>
     <li>Menu item 4<a href="#"></a></li>
     <li>Menu item 5<a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>    
   </nav>   
  </header>
  <aside class="sidebour">
      <h3></h3>
      <nav class="left-menu"></nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          </ul>    
  </aside>
  <main class="content">
   <h1>WELCOME TO MY PAGE!</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
   <h2>Look at my photos</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
   <figure class="image">
    <img src="sky.png">
    <figcaption>Picture1</figcaption>
   </figure>
   <figure class="image2">
    <img src="see.png">
    <figcaption>Picture2</figcaption>
   </figure> 
  </main>
  <footer>
   <p class="copy">Copyright © 2017 All rights reserved</p>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <!-- Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svvhD.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svvhD.png)

Comment: aside и main оберните в какой не будь div и этому div в css напишите display: flex ; и всё

Comment: можно просто две `figure` обернуть и `flex` ему